# PHP date returning wrong value

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone

I have a date format like this 'Tue May 01 00:00:00 +1000 2012' (from array data on json file)

when I use date() function it returning April, :D

```
      echo date('F Y', strtotime('Tue May 01 00:00:00 +1000 2012'));

      //it returning "April 2012"
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Many Thanks!

Comment: What's your aim? How It should appear then?

Comment: Notice the timezone specification on the provided date/time? When it's May 1st over there, it's still April 31 on your own timezone. How to fix it? You can simply remove the `+1000` to get the result you want, but I 'm not sure if that's fixing or breaking it.

Comment: There is no such date as April 31, Jon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the old date/time functions that mess things up because they implicitly involve your local time zone, use [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
$date = new DateTime('Tue May 01 00:00:00 +1000 2012');
echo $date->format('F Y');
```

This will also work corrrectly for *any* date, regardless of the timezone (UTC+10 hours or anything else).

Answer (score 2):

You will need to check both the timezones. Or set a custom one for both `date` and `strtotime` calls.

---

Since you are using `+1000` as your timezone-offset; I'm assuming it is Australia. You can use the `date_default_timezone_set()` call to set timezone to **Australia**.

```
echo date('F Y', strtotime('Tue May 01 00:00:00 +1000 2012'));
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Queensland');
echo date('F Y', strtotime('Tue May 01 00:00:00 +1000 2012'));
```

Here is the codepad link: http://codepad.org/tPC8DEQp

Comment: Irrelevant. The timezone is specified inline in the input.

Comment: @hjpotter92: This will only work for dates where the TZ specification is `+1000` -- in which case, why (globally) change the timezone instead of (locally) removing the +1000 from the string? Also, Queensland does not observe DST right now, but it could do so in the future (as it has in the past) and if that happens then you have a bug. So even if you wanted to change the TZ, it would be better to change it to [`Etc/GMT+10`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php).

Comment: @Jon Using `Etc/GMT-10` seems to solve the problem now: http://codepad.org/kxQj2sEO

Comment: @hjpotter92: Right, -10 is correct. But all of these solutions are less than satisfactory. I have added an answer of my own.